# Referring to an ENV variable through javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics, and refer to different tracking ids based on environment.  I have a sandbox version of google analytics that has one id, running in a staging environment, and a production version of Google Analytics that has another id, running in a production environment.

I'm setting these ids as environment variables, and the goal is to just call the environment variable ENV["GA_TRACKING_ID"] to set the tracking in my javascript file, and automatically set the id based on which environment is running.

However, I keep getting `ReferenceError: ENV is not defined`

***Update:***

```
class @GoogleAnalytics
  @load: ->
    window._gaq = []
    window._gaq.push ["_setAccount", GoogleAnalytics.analyticsId()]
    # other GA configuration

  @analyticsId: ->
    gon.ga_tracking_id

GoogleAnalytics.load()
```

And used accepted answer's gem and ApplicationController code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :assign_env_variables

  def assign_env_variables
    gon.ga_tracking_id = ENV["GA_TRACKING_ID"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Show how you are calling it from the javascript, and from which file.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Inside a GoogleAnalytics.load function, `window._gaq.push ["_setAccount", GoogleAnalytics.analyticsId()]`

Inside the analyticsId() function, `ENV['GA_TRACKING_ID']`

And at the end I call `GoogleAnalytics.load()`

Comment: Please provide the full code. It's not clear if you are placing the ENV inside a Ruby block, and from which template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like this gem for passing back-end variables to Javascript:

https://github.com/gazay/gon

In your application_controller.rb, you can then add a before_action filter to run a method which means it will load on every page. Using gon you can use code such as this to assign variables:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :assign_env_variables

  def assign_env_variables
    gon.ga_tracking_id = ENV["GA_TRACKING_ID"]
  end
end
```

As long as you include the line for gon in the template head (as per the documentation) you can then use this anywhere in your JS files to access that variable:

```
gon.ga_tracking_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Worked like a charm.